# Javascript To PHP File Upload Missing Bytes

Tags: php, iis, file-upload

I need to upload files from javascript to php for binary reading and it seems to be adding an extra 0 byte at the beginning and skipping one at the end.

Javascript Code:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("files[]", fileInput.files[0]);

uploadButton.classList.add("is-loading");


fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData
       }).then(response => {
           if(response.status === 200) showContent(fileInput.files[0].name);
       });
```

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_FILES["files"])) {
      $name = $_FILES["files"]["name"][0];
      $tmp = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][0];

      $path = "";

      do { $newName = str_replace(".uexp", "", $name) . "-" . generateRandomString(); $path = "../filestore/$newName.uexp"; } while(file_exists($path));

      move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path);

      $str = file_get_contents($path);
      $byteArray = unpack("C*", $str);

      $_SESSION["Name"] = $name;
      $_SESSION["Path"] = $path;
      $_SESSION["File"] = serialize($byteArray);
  }
```

When I read out the file in the filestore directory (so after move_uploaded_file) it is different than the one originally uploaded.

The file that was originally uploaded starts with (in hex): EA 00 00 and ends with (in hex): 83 2A 9E. The file that can be found in the filestore folder starts with (in hex): 00 EA 00 and ends with (in hex): 83 2A.

As a result, the file can no longer be read by the original application. I'm using PHP 7.2 and IIS as my platform.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: as an aaside: You'' get an endless loop when you get a collision on the randomstring:  move the "$newname - .... statement into the do { } while loop ...

Comment: Is it just the start and end  where the bytes get ordered differently ? or is it the entire file ?

Comment: @swa66 Whoops, didn't see that for infinite loop for some reason. And it's just the start and the end. Everything is in a different place though thanks the 0 being added at the beginning

Comment: So essentially you're saying the file gets padded by a 0x00 in front of the file, yet the length remains the same (so the last original byte is chopped off) ?

Comment: To debug it, maybe try to isolate the client from the server a bit: try to upload it using a plain html form and try a different file (maybe a really short text file) also try to debug it all in the browser to see what it sends over the wire.

As to IIS: "I don't do windows", so those that do might have a better idea.

Comment: @swa66 Yep, seems to be Windows(IIS) problem since I just tested it on linux with apache2 and it works just fine... Same PHP Version.

Comment: Maybe update your question to tag IIS and add more info on versions of windows, ISS etc.

Comment: Are these files packed?  Why are you using **unpack**?